# Update DataKeyNames field value in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, asp.net-3.5

I am using gridview for add and update process in database.

Process Flow:

**Name     A     B     C    Command**

**xx**                                               Add

**yy**     12      13     13  Update

**zz**     22      33     44  Update

1. The first record does not have value in datakey field because there is no record in the database
2. The Second record has data key because it has the record available.
3. I want to update the datakey field value of the gridview after add process done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking about; but the row's **DataKey** field in a GridView is updated every time you bind the GridView to a data source, calling the `DataBind()` method.

So, after you have added a new record, just load the data source and bind the GridView to it, and the DataKey fields will have the new values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to update the datakey value without rebinding the gridview?

Comment: That's not possible. Just look at the DataKey.Value property: it's a get-only property.